# How to print vector class type contents

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am having problem to print out the vector that hold my person info.

```
struct PersonInfo{

    string name;
    vector<string> phones;  
};

int main(){

    string line, word;
    vector<PersonInfo> people;
    while(getline(cin, line)){
        PersonInfo info;
        istringstream record(line);
        record >> info.name;
        while(record >> word)
            info.phones.push_back(word);
        people.push_back(info);

    }
    for(auto i = people.begin(); i != people.end(); i++)
         cout << people << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching at all how to print an object in C++? And take a look at you `for` statement. What's the point of creating an iterator to the `vector` if you never use it within the body of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
          cout << people << endl;
                  ^
```

You need to define `<<` operator for your custom struct. Define it after the struct like this

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const PersonInfo & p) {
    out << p.name << endl;
    copy(p.phones.begin(), p.phones.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(out, " "));
    return out;
}
```

and correct your print statement

```
for (auto i : people)
    cout << i << endl;
```

See working demo at http://ideone.com/uLSLHY.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Using iterator

   ```
   for(auto i = people.begin(); i != people.end(); i++)
   {
       cout << i->name<< endl;
       for ( auto l= i->phones.begin(); l != i->phones.end(); ++l)
           std::cout<< *l<<"\n";
   }
   ```
2. using range loop

   ```
   for ( auto & val: people)
   {
       std::cout<<val.name<<"\n";
       for ( auto & phone: val.phones)
           std::cout<<phone;
   }
   ```
3. You can use vector index, left to you as home work

Comment: Your examples are mislabelled.

Comment: Wrong operator for iterators

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < people.size(); i++){
         cout << people[i].name<< endl;

      for(int j = 0 ;j<people[i].phones.size() ; j++)
           cout<< people[i].phones[j]<<" ";

      cout<<endl;      
 }
```

Here in using the first loop we are iterating until the size of vector people and as each of the content in vector people has another vector named phones so we need to iterate that one too. we did this in the second loop.

So if people[0] has phone size 10 then we will iterate

people[0].phones[10] and so on..

Comment: Adding a little explanation to your answer will make it a better answer.